# Change the background color of specific cells

Tags: javascript, css

I have made this Formative Assessments Tracker for my school such that the number inputed in the required is the basis if the cell's background color will either be green if they are the same and red if they are not.

It is functionioning but it only affects the first cell. I am wondering if I have to make the id's different or if there is a way to do it in a much shorter and less hectic way so that all cells get affected with the one click of the button.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Formative Assessments Tracker</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: helvetica;
                font-size: 20px;
                padding: 40px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            td {
                padding: 20px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .green {
                background-color: green;
                padding: 10px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .gray {
                background-color: gray;
                padding: 50px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .red {
                background-color: red;
                padding: 10px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .white {
                background-color: white;
                padding: 10px;
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>

        <body>
            <h3>HIGH SCHOOL</h3>
            <h2>FORMATIVE ASSESSMENTS TRACKER</h2> # of FAs that should have been submitted:
            <input type="text" id="required">
            <button onclick="submission()">Submit</button>

            <script>
                function submission() {
                    var r = document.getElementById("required").value;
                    var s = document.getElementById("submitted").value;
                    if (r == s) {
                        document.getElementById('name').style.backgroundColor = "green";
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById('name').style.backgroundColor = "red";
                    }
                }
            </script>

            <table border="1">

                <tr>
                    <td id="name" class="green">NAME</td>
                    <td id="name" class="green">NAME</td>


     <td id="name" class="green">NAME</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="gray" </td>
                    <td class="gray" </td>
                        <td class="gray" </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="white"># of FAs Submitted:
                    <input type="text" id="submitted">
                </td>
                <td class="white"># of FAs Submitted:
                    <input type="text" id="submitted">
                </td>
                <td class="white"># of FAs Submitted:
                    <input type="text" id="submitted">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td id="name" class="green">NAME</td>
                <td id="name" class="green">NAME</td>
                <td id="name" class="green">NAME</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="gray" </td>
                    <td class="gray" </td>
                        <td class="gray" </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="white"># of FAs Submitted:
                    <input type="text" id="submitted">
                </td>
                <td class="white"># of FAs Submitted:
                    <input type="text" id="submitted">
                </td>
                <td class="white"># of FAs Submitted:
                    <input type="text" id="submitted">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td id="name" class="green">NAME</td>
                <td id="name" class="green">NAME</td>
                <td id="name" class="green">NAME</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="gray" </td>
                    <td class="gray" </td>
                        <td class="gray" </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="white"># of FAs Submitted:
                    <input type="text" id="submitted">
                </td>
                <td class="white"># of FAs Submitted:
                    <input type="text" id="submitted">
                </td>
                <td class="white"># of FAs Submitted:
                    <input type="text" id="submitted">
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>

    </body>
```

Comment: An id (unlike classes) should only be used by a single element on the page. If they have the same class, you can target them by that.

Comment: Try applying the styles to the class name instead of the id name, as @Moishe Lipsker said, the id's have to be unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your code to fix your problem.

The answer is yes you should use different Ids for every element. But you could use **classes** to kind of 'group' elements and then get them using methods like **getElementsByClassName**
I implemented classes and the method getElementsByClassName in your code, and now it's working.

here is your the code:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Formative Assessments Tracker</title>

  <style>
    body {
      font-family: helvetica;
      font-size: 20px;
      padding: 40px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    td {
      padding: 20px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .green {
      background-color: green;
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .gray {
      background-color: gray;
      padding: 50px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .red {
      background-color: red;
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .white {
      background-color: white;
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>



  <h3>HIGH SCHOOL</h3>
  <h2>FORMATIVE ASSESSMENTS TRACKER</h2>
  # of FAs that should have been submitted:
  <input type="text" id="required">
  <button onclick="submission()">Submit</button>

  <script>
    function submission() {
      var r = document.getElementById("required").value;
      var sElements = document.getElementsByClassName("submitted");
      for (i = 0; i < sElements.length; i++) {
        if(sElements[i].value == r){
          sElements[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";
        }else{
          sElements[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
      }
    }
  </script>

  <table border="1">

    <tr>
      <td id="name" class="green">NAME</td>
      <td id="name" class="green">NAME</td>
      <td id="name" class="green">NAME</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="gray" </td>
        <td class="gray" </td>
          <td class="gray" </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="white"># of FAs Submitted:
        <input type="text" class="submitted">
      </td>
      <td class="white"># of FAs Submitted:
        <input type="text" class="submitted">
      </td>
      <td class="white"># of FAs Submitted:
        <input type="text" class="submitted">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td id="name" class="green">NAME</td>
      <td id="name" class="green">NAME</td>
      <td id="name" class="green">NAME</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="gray" </td>
        <td class="gray" </td>
          <td class="gray" </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="white"># of FAs Submitted:
        <input type="text" class="submitted">
      </td>
      <td class="white"># of FAs Submitted:
        <input type="text" class="submitted">
      </td>
      <td class="white"># of FAs Submitted:
        <input type="text" class="submitted">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td id="name" class="green">NAME</td>
      <td id="name" class="green">NAME</td>
      <td id="name" class="green">NAME</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="gray" </td>
        <td class="gray" </td>
          <td class="gray" </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="white"># of FAs Submitted:
        <input type="text" class="submitted">
      </td>
      <td class="white"># of FAs Submitted:
        <input type="text" class="submitted">
      </td>
      <td class="white"># of FAs Submitted:
        <input type="text" class="submitted">
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you please explain the function submission part? I wasn't taught the [i] and the like... Btw thank you, everything is working fine I just need to know how that part works.

Comment: Basically you need to learn about Arrays. sElements is an Array object which has all of the elements that have the 'submitted' class. To access an element inside of an Array, you use the index. I recommend you to take a look at this link: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering if I have to make the id's different

[**YES**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute)

Unique id's are required.

> or if there is a way to do it in a much shorter and less hectic way

**YES**

Make sure your inputs have something in common, then use any of the following (non-exhaustive list):

- [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)
- [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)
- [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

For example, change all of your duplicate id's of `submitted` and `name` to classes, then use `getElementsByClassName` and a loop or `[].forEach.call`.

Also, `<td class="gray"</td>` is invalid HTML. You need another closing angle bracket: `<td class="gray"></td>`.

```js
function submission () {
    var r = document.getElementById('required').value,
        s = document.getElementsByClassName('submitted'),
        n = document.getElementsByClassName('name');

    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (r === s[i].value)
            n[i].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        else
            n[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}

td {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.green {
    background-color: green;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.gray {
    background-color: gray;
    padding: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

.red {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.white {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h3>HIGH SCHOOL</h3>
<h2>FORMATIVE ASSESSMENTS TRACKER</h2> # of FAs that should have been submitted:
<input type="text" id="required">
<button onclick="submission()">Submit</button>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td class="name green">NAME</td>
        <td class="name green">NAME</td>
        <td class="name green">NAME</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="gray"></td>
        <td class="gray"></td>
        <td class="gray"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="white"># of FAs Submitted:
            <input type="text" class="submitted">
        </td>
        <td class="white"># of FAs Submitted:
            <input type="text" class="submitted">
        </td>
        <td class="white"># of FAs Submitted:
            <input type="text" class="submitted">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="name green">NAME</td>
        <td class="name green">NAME</td>
        <td class="name green">NAME</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="gray"></td>
        <td class="gray"></td>
        <td class="gray"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="white"># of FAs Submitted:
            <input type="text" class="submitted">
        </td>
        <td class="white"># of FAs Submitted:
            <input type="text" class="submitted">
        </td>
        <td class="white"># of FAs Submitted:
            <input type="text" class="submitted">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="name green">NAME</td>
        <td class="name green">NAME</td>
        <td class="name green">NAME</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="gray"></td>
        <td class="gray"></td>
        <td class="gray"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="white"># of FAs Submitted:
            <input type="text" class="submitted">
        </td>
        <td class="white"># of FAs Submitted:
            <input type="text" class="submitted">
        </td>
        <td class="white"># of FAs Submitted:
            <input type="text" class="submitted">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the class names instead of id's:

```
<script>
    function submission(){
       var r = document.getElementById("required").value;
       var s = document.getElementById("submitted").value;
       if (r==s){
           document.getElementsByClassName('green').style.backgroundColor="green";
       }
       else{
           document.getElementsByClassName('green').style.backgroundColor="red";
       }
     }
</script>
```